# Why do I get the error: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "char*" in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to print the keys (the char) on a display, I have programmed both keypad and display. I am trying now to let the user write the time using the keyboard and it should print the time if it is valid.

I am currently trying to create a function that prints the time on a display. I have implemented a function called printArray(char Arr[]) that looks like this:

```
void printArray(char Arr[]) {
  int n = 0;
  while(Arr[n] != 0){
    printkeys(Arr[n]);
    n++;
  }
}
```

the printkeys method prints writes the numbers into ascii code (made it in previous project and it works)

my time function I want to print looks like this:

```
void Timettt(char Arr[], char x, char y){
  printArray((Arr[0]/10 + ASCIIOFFSET));
  printArray((Arr[0]%10 + ASCIIOFFSET));
  putchar(':');
  printArray((Arr[1]/10 + ASCIIOFFSET));
  printArray((Arr[1]%10 + ASCIIOFFSET));
  putchar(':');
  printArray((Arr[2]/10 + ASCIIOFFSET));
  printArray((Arr[2]%10 + ASCIIOFFSET));
}
```

When I compile the code I get error on the printArray parts in Timettt function saying:
argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "char*"

I have no idea why it shows up when all my functions inclusive the print keys function are void and with the argument type char.

I would gladly accept any help/tips you can give

I have tried to compile it and change the Timettt function in other ways but I still get the same error

Comment: Looks like `Timettt()` is passing only a single `char` to the output function... It does not look like it is passing an array of characters (aka a C string). Try replacing those 6 calls with a simple `putchar()` call... Worth trying...

Comment: Why are you even using `char` for your array? If you have an array of integers please use either `int` (if the values can be negative) or `unsigned` (of the values can't be negative).

Comment: OT: `printf( "%02d:%02d:%02d", Arr[0], Arr[1], Arr[2] );` What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Since `Timettt()` is converting the array of h, m, s to six individual ASCII digits, change the six calls to `printArray()` to call the single character output function `putchar()` instead... You appear to use `putchar()` to output the colon separator. Do the same for each digit.

Answer (score 2):

`char Arr[]` is a pointer to an array of `char`, so `Arr[0]` is a `char`.

a `char` divided by ten and added to (what I have to assume is) a numerical constant is an `int` due to integer promotion rules for integer types representable by `int`.

I have no idea why you are *trying to do*, but what your code says is you want to pass an integer value to a function that is expecting a pointer to a `char` array, which makes no sense, which is why your compiler is complaining.